# What is the difference between picture-in-picture and multi-window mode in Android?

Tags: android, android-picture-in-picture

In Google I/O 2017, Picture-in-picture mode was introduced.How is it different from multi-window mode?

Comment: check https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/use-new-picture-picture-mode-android-o-0178324/

Answer (score 4):

MultiWindow is split-screen

[image]

Two Apps at the same time

---

Picture in Picture is an image overlay

[image]

One App, Two Views at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Picture-in picture mode is for Android 7.0 TV users to provide the pinned video overlay window whereas multi-window mode keeps activities side by side.

Picture-in picture mode is not enabled by default.But if app targets API level 24,multi-window support is enabled by default.